# &nbsp; character taking up space

Tags: html, css

Odd title, I agree but let me explain.

Here is the div code:

```
<div>
{{   internet }} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{   breakfast }} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{   parking }}
</div>
```

When the three database results aren't used, the div still takes up vertical space on the page.

How would I have this div be flat if there is no data but the non breaking spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces around the `&nbsp;` characters, which will still count as whitespace. Try this:

```
<div>{{ internet }}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ breakfast }}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ parking }}</div>
```

You can also use CSS to specify you don't want the div to wrap, which IMO is cleaner:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">...</div>
```

Comment: do you mean the white spaces on either side of the two non breaking spaces?

Comment: Yep, plus there's whitespace at the beginning of and end of the `div` content.

Comment: This will still take up space though. You are actually only saving a single white space character here (leading and trailing ones are ignored, consecutive ones collapse). But maybe I'm also not understanding the question.

Comment: Looks like that did it, thank you. Can't believe it was that easy... lol Will accept it when 10 minutes pass as the site advised me I can't until then.

Comment: @FelixKling: where is there whitespace? I assume the `{{ }}` is collapsed into a single token.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is white space. They don't collapse.

Comment: Ah, I was talking whitespace from a DOM parsing perspective.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about how it's rendered. Converting `&nbsp; {{ breakfast }} &nbsp;` to `&nbsp;{{ breakfast }}&nbsp;` is actually the only effective change. Any other "real" white space character is not rendered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just non-breaking spaces by themselves are enough to give your div vertical space. You can deal with this inside the data elements themselves, possibly with some server code.

For example, I don't know how your `internet`, `breakfast`, and `parking` fields are populated, but you could have a new property called `combinedFields`, which concatenates all three of them, applying spaces appropriately as needed, or would be an empty string if all values are empty.

Then your markup would just be:

```
<div>{{ combinedFields }}</div>
```

If `combinedFields` was empty, then the result would just be `<div></div>` and would take up no vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect in Javascript if you have content in your div this way:

```
var someDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i=0;i<someDiv.length;i++){
    var text = someDiv[i].innerText.trim(); //kick out all the space with no utility
    if(text.length<=0){
        someDiv[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

If you want to test : http://jsfiddle.net/Lwpepz0z/ .
It will be more easy if you have an id on your div so no more need of the loop.